# How can I facilitate concurrent users on a Google Apps Script Webapp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, concurrency, locking

I'm currently creating a webapp that reads and writes to a Google Sheet. It is essentially a form app which takes inputs from a HTML form, writes it into a sheet using `appendRow()` (and subsequent use of `getRange()` and `setValue()` to append further data onto that row). Each row represents an instance of the form being filled. See example code of the write process.

```
/*
Function that is called in Index.html whenever the 'Next' button pressed. This 
gets all inputs from HTML form and stores them in the spreadsheet.

Parameters:
inputArray: a 1x3 array which contains the owner, reference and type of scale.
*/

function addProjectInputs(inputArray) {
  var sheetName = "Inputs";
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  Logger.log(sheet);
  var d = new Date();
  var tz = spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var d = [Utilities.formatDate(d,tz,  "dd/MM/yyyy")];
  var data = d.concat(inputArray);
  Logger.log(data);
  sheet.appendRow(data);
}

/* Function to append further data onto the row created from 
addProjectInputs() */

function addFurtherInputs(idlerArray) {
  var sheetName = "Inputs";
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()-42;

  var arrayEmpty = idlerArray.every(function(i) { return i === ''; });
  Logger.log(arrayEmpty);

  if (arrayEmpty !== true) {
    for (i = 0; i < idlerArray.length; i++) {
      var range3 = sheet.getRange(lastRow,lastColumn+1+i,1,1);
      range3.setValue(idlerArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

The summary page of the app (page 5, appears after all writing steps) then reads this data (using `.getRange().getValues()`) and then displays them on the page.

This works fine when one user is on it - however this app will get used by up to 20 people, potentially concurrently. This is an issue. For example, if a second user were to start using the app, their data would then start overwriting the first user's by adding a new row, thus 'archiving' the first user's data. I've come across the following potential solutions:

1. Making use of the LockService to force only one person to use the app at a time (not ideal since the app would be used for quoting customers and don't really want to keep users waiting).
2. Multithreading
3. Stacks

I'm not sure how 2 or 3 would work, or even possible in GAS. Could anyone please shed some light on if it is possible to facilitate multiple users, and how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need more info here, and ideally some example code. You are reading and writing, but are those things happening in sequence, Eg reading after writing, or do you read at one step and write at another? Does data being written affect later reads? Are you writing single rows, or complex sheets? There are a variety of strategies that could be employed, from simply using appendRow, to locking, session management, etc. Depending on the complexity of your front end.

Comment: Hey Cameron, have edited the original post to provide more detail. Hopefully that clarifies things further :)

Comment: how many seconds does it take to run? If you have it wait 30 seconds for lockservice that should allow a 1 second script to handle 20 people with no problems. If it is a 2 minute script then you have a different issue.

Comment: Each script takes ~2 seconds to execute. The thing is, this webapp has 4 stages of inputs (i.e. 4 pages and thus 4 write script executions to the sheet), so a second user could be on the third page while the first user is on the fourth page, so when the second user submits the third page, it will overwrite the submission of the first user's third page submission. I hope that makes sense, I know it may seem a bit convoluted lol

Comment: So exactly your problem is that after appending a row you don have a way to keep track of that row? Couldn't you just give an ID, or return the number of row so you can keep track of later? That way you could do it with multiple people working in the same page.

Comment: Ok with that information, I'd suggest that rather than appending a row after the first page, write all of your input to user specific properties along the way and then spit that out as a single line at the end.

Comment: Hi @Emile You just deleted the post I had the answer to. https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/spreadsheet-closest_match_analog/closest_match_analog.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than locking, I would approach this by generating a unique ID for each user session, which you can store in the sheet and use to match up the values later.

On your entry point [probably doGet(), maybe doPost()], generate a UUID with `var session_id = Utilities.getUuid();`

Then pass that sessiond ID to your template, and include it in all future requests back to the Apps Script.

Write the UUID to a column in the sheet in your `addProjectInputs()` function, then modify your `addFurtherInputs()` function to locate the correct row based on the UUID, (rather than always taking the last one) and write your updates to that row.

This approach guarantees you can have many users working without worrying about overwriting each other, and with no delays due to locks.

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#getUuid()

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know, thanks heaps!!

Comment: So the issue I'm having is that this program serves multiple templates; meaning that when I get the ID in the first page, this variable would then disappear once the second page is served. These subsequent pages are where the further inputs are written to the sheet. Is there a way to propagate that ID variable through subsequent pages?

Comment: All good, I've managed to make use of User Properties in Properties service. Thanks heaps for your help!

Comment: glad this has helped Emile.  Sounds like you have a workable solution but in reply to your earlier comment,  if using multiple templates you need a way to propagate that ID between each template. I would usually do this by passing it back to whichever function pulls the next template.  If you are using one function to furnish all of them (eg doGet() displays all the templates), I would add a check to use an existing ID if it's passed in, or generate a new one if it's not. In the templates I would modify each to pass the ID back to Apps Script as the user navigates between pages.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of those solutions.

1. LockService works well even for large sheets and more users. You need to track the frequency of actions of your users. If you don’t use a simulated web socket behavior you’re usually afraid of nothing.
2. Multithreading is not applicable here.
3. Stacks. If I understand you correctly, the stacks are organized based on sheets and formulas. Usually I divide my Sheets Apps by access level and by type of actions. About access everything is clear. Types of action: push, calculates, pull. Each sheet has only one action. I use `appendRow` unary entries for push. And also I use classes to calculate what will be in the push. This allows me to save one call and not take `pull.getDataRange().getValues()` every time after I write to pull. I use formulas so that pull is always relevant. You must be familiar with the concepts of "slice of the past", "balances for the period" in order to realize this.

It can be a little foggy because I speak English poorly. My apologize.