# Concurrent uses of Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I've created a simple signup form that takes in the persons name & email, saves it to a database and gives him a seven digit code in return from a database. Each code can only belong to one person. The code is run under my user from Google App Scripts.

I'm now wondering, if I need to use Lockservice or anything else to allow for concurrent use of the program? If the 2 people use this program at the same time for example, would this likely cause any problems - **in example that the input.name would be from the answers of one user accessing the script  and input.email would be originated from another?**  A simple illustration of my code

```
document.getElementById("registerBtn").addEventListener("click",register);

function register (){

//take values from input
var input = {};
input.name = document.getElementById("namefield").value;
input.email = document.getElementById("emailfield").value;

if (input.email && input.name) {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successfun).withFailureHandler(failurefun).checkInfo(input)
}else{
      M.toast({html: 'Please insert your data'});
}}

function successfun (output){
      M.toast({html: 'Your code is:' + output});
}

function failurefun (output){
      M.toast({html: 'This name or email have already been registered'});
}


/// ... Google Scripts:

function checkInfo(input) {
// open google spreadsheet
//check with indexOf if the email exists
//if the email does not exist, check if name exists
//if the name does not exist - append new row.
//if this is successful, open up another tab and take the first value from there, that does not have 2 //next to it & change the value next to it to 2.
//return confirmation code;

//If name or email exist: return error; 
}
```

// Editing the question taking the guidance from the comment into account: If I'd have the script run not from my account but from each individual user, I would not have this issue?

Comment: When LockService is used, for example, when 2 users run the Google Apps Script, the script is run for one user and the script is not run for another user. After the script for 1st user was done, the script is run for another user. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) In your script, when you want to use LockService, it is required to add to Google Apps Script `checkInfo(input)`. For this, the threads in Stackoverflow might be useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+LockService)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tanaike! Just to understand better - would this mean that only 1 person could access the code at any given time, correct? In example: If user 1 has inputted his information & has clicked  the registration button - a second user cannot access the code (or if he can, he can only receive his code back after user 2), correct?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `In example` in your replying. LockService is for Google Apps Script. In your script, your script in your question is the script for the client side. So in this case, when `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successfun).withFailureHandler(failurefun).checkInfo(input)` is run, the LockService is run. So for example, when 2 users click the button of `registerBtn`, the value of `input` of `checkInfo(input)` is used in Google Apps Script side in order of users.

Answer (score 1):

*According to the Apps Script Lock Service [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock):*

> `Lock Service` allows scripts to **prevent concurrent access to sections of code**. This can be useful when you have multiple users or processes modifying a shared resource and want to prevent collisions.

Thus, since this is an Apps Script service, *it can be used only in your Apps Script code* and later called from the HTML code.

You might also want to take a look at the Apps Script's [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), which states that you can get at most 30 simultaneously executions.

An alternative to your approach is the solution proposed in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59771586) which suggests to make use of the  `Utilities.getUuid()`.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock);
- [Apps Script Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas);
- [How can I facilitate concurrent users on a Google Apps Script Webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760841/how-can-i-facilitate-concurrent-users-on-a-google-apps-script-webapp);
- [Apps Script Utilites Class - getUuid()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#getuuid).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ale13! Looking @ my Q, I think I didn't explain this as well as I could have. Basically I'm wondering how does JS differentiate between two different but concurrent executions? Ex: If two users fill in the form at the same time, how does it know that input.name from one user should be linked with input.email with the same user, instead of taking the input.name from user 1 and input.email from user 2 who is filling in the form at the same time? I ran some tests with the actual code, and there are no issues with this in reality, but to be fair - I cannot understand why/how.